# How to access a subclass using a string variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a stucture of classes and subclasses as follows:

```
public class Regions
    {
        public const string UNITEDSTATES = "United States";
        public static string[] members = { UNITEDSTATES};

        public static class UnitedStatesTypes
        {
            public const string STEEL = "steel";
            public const string CONCRETE = "concrete";
            public static string[] members = { STEEL, CONCRETE };

            public static class SteelStandards
            {
                public const string A36 = "ASTM A36";
                public static string[] members = { A36 };

                public static class A36Grades
                {
                    public const string GRADE_36 = "Grade 36";
                    public static string[] members = { GRADE_36 };
                }
            public static class ConcreteStandards
            {
                ...
            }
```

There are more values under each one of the classes, but this is just a small sample so you can get the idea of what it looks like. I am trying to create a UI to select each one of these. There are 4 dropdown menus, each menu is populated by the value of the higher menu. So if the standards dropdown is on SteelStandards, the next dropdown is populated with A36, if it was on ConcreteStandards the next would be populated with the data under ConcreteStandards. Is there a way that I can access a subclass using a string variable?

For example, the first dropdown will select United States. The next dropdown needs to piece together "UnitedStatesTypes" and then access Regions.UnitedStatesTypes.members. I have tried using braces

```
Regions["UnitedStatesTypes"].members
```

but this did not work. Is there a way to make this happen? Or is there a better way to organize my data?

Comment: Four nested public classes? Honestly? Seems like a really bad design, IMHO. It seems you should have a `Dictionary` instead.

Comment: You can, using reflection, but you'd need a way to map eg the string "steel" to the member name `SteelStandards` - which becomes pointless. As @Him said - a dictionary is what you're after.

Comment: Restructure this with a Dictionary

Comment: How can I create a 4 level dictionary? Would the high level dictionary have values that are "sub dictionaries"?

Comment: @UltraSaucy an object model containing `Text` & `Children` - i'll write up an answer.

Comment: I just found [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/three-dimensional-dictionary-in-C-Sharp/), it looks like exactly what I need

Comment: @UltraSaucy looks good. You might also want to check my updated answer - it might be a bit better for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with just dictionaries, albeit it gets a bit unwieldy as you go down the tree:

```
var regions = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,List<string>>>>>();
// populate it. Yes I know how ugly that will look!
var usSteelStandards = regions["United States"]["Steel"]["Standards"];
```

A better way might be to refactor your code as a set of class instances, instead of trying to use static classes/members all the way. It is a typical tree structure

```
public class Node : IEnumerable<Node>
{
   public Node(string text)
   {
        this.Text = text;
       this.Children = new List<Node>(); 
   }
   public string Text {get; private set;}
   public List<Node> Children { get; private set;} 

   public Node this[string childText]
   {
      get{ return this.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == childText); }
   } 

   public void Add(string text, params Node[] childNodes)
   {
       var node = new Node(text);
       node.Children.AddRange(childNodes);
       this.Children.Add(node);
   }

    public IEnumerator<Node> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Children.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This can then be setup and used much easier

```
var node = new Node("root")
{
    {
        "United States", 
         new Node("Steel")
         {
             {
                 "ASTM A36",
                 new Node("Grade 36")
             }
         },
         new Node("Concrete")
         {

         }
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(node["United States"].Children.Count);
Console.WriteLine(node["United States"]["Steel"]["ASTM A36"].Children[0].Text);
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/QVGN99585